# Does ROS_INFO break realtime?

Tags: ros, ros-info, ros-control, realtime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the realtime lost if I use ROS_INFO inside a ros_control controller update method or inside a ros_control hardware interface write/read method?

edit:
this question may have different answers according with the real time environment you are using, for instance (Xenomai or RT-Preempt)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302486/does-ros_info-break-realtime?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
Btw: this is not specific to `ros_control`. Any deterministic context in which `ROS_* log macros are used would be affected similarly.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2018-09-05**:
Developing controllers or hardware nodes via ros_control is some kind of "standard approach" to interface hardware and develop your control algorithms.

I assumed here that in general for any controller is desirable to be real time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
I meant to say with my comment that even without `ros_control`, but in a general situation where deterministic execution is desired, using `ROS_INFO(..)` or any of the other variants will probably have exactly the same effect.

`ros_control` is not special.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2018-09-09**:
We are in agreement, ros_control is not special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is the realtime lost if I use ROS_INFO inside a ros_control controller update method or inside a ros_control hardware interface write/read method?

<del>yes.</del> It depends / probably.

In the end, `ROS_INFO(..)` gets expanded to [ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER(filter, ...)](https://github.com/ros/rosconsole/blob/1f0a73aff15ec7f4a4803cbdb3362a128949154f/include/ros/console.h#L345) which calls `::ros::console::print(..)` which in the end makes use of either `printf(..)`, `fprintf(..)` or a function in that group and/or calls upon one of the [backends](https://github.com/ros/rosconsole/tree/1f0a73aff15ec7f4a4803cbdb3362a128949154f/src/rosconsole/impl) (`glog`, `log4cxx`) to do the work.

Unless a custom implementation of the `printf(..)` family is used, calling it typically results in loss of determinism. Xenomai wraps `printf(..)` and could work-around this. Not sure about RT-PREEMPT.

But apart from that there are multiple places where objects are instantiated and functions in various libraries are called. Those are also a bit suspect.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2018-09-05**:
Thanks. I guess that the precise question would be. "Can be used ROS_INFO in a realtime controller?"
Xenomai: yes
RT-PREEMPT: ??
I can edit the question if you agree

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
No, I don't think you can conclude: Xenomai, yes.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2018-09-06**:
okok. Specifically what i was looking for is if that ROS_INFO would break the realtime. That is the question. I am going to rename the title of the cuestion to "does ROS_INFO break realtime?"